# Copying files in Finder with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

This is my first attempt at AppleScripting.

I have 3 folders that contain image files.
Test Folder 1 has 77 large, master files.
Test Folder 2 has 4 smaller files in a subfolder called ABC with the same name as files in Test Folder 1.
Test Folder 3 Contains an empty sub folder called ABC.
I want a script to check the file names in Test Folder 2 and copy the equivalent file names from Test Folder 1 to Test Folder 3 subfolder ABC

Here is what I have so far:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set the_files to (files of folder "Macintosh HD:Users:Ronnie:Pictures:Test Folder 1:")
    set the_file_names to (files of folder "Macintosh HD:Users:Ronnie:Pictures:Test Folder 2:ABC:")
    set target_folder to ("Macintosh HD:Users:Ronnie:Pictures:Test Folder 3:ABC:")
    if document files of the_file_names is equal to document files of the_files then duplicate the_files to target_folder
end tell
```

Currently it will copy all the files from Test Folder 1 so its seams that the "If" script does not work.

Can someone help?

Ronnie

Comment: I think I know what you're doing, and I've formulated an answer, but I need to know 1 thing: when testing for the files in test folder 1 matching files in test folder 2, would a duplication only be done if all the file names exactly matched, or are you simply wanting to copy files that match?

Comment: In other words, there may be files in one folder that don't exist in the other. if such a mismatch is found, the way I have it now, such a file is ignored, but other files with a match are copied.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Only files that match need to be copied. Hope you can help. I am teaching myself and have hit the wall on this one and I am hoping to learn with your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it.

```
--this is my preference. I prefer to work with strings then coerce them to aliases
--"aliases" in the old AppleScript/Mac API sense, meaning special file/folder path data type
-- (this is what is returned when you use the choose file or choose folder commands, e.g.)
--  aliases can be coerced to and from strings
-- not to be confused with POSIX style paths which use "/" as separator, OR
-- Finder item objects, which are specific to the Finder ('file x of folder y of startup disk z' style)

set tf1 to "Macintosh HD:Users:Ronnie:Pictures:Test Folder 1:"
set tf2 to "Macintosh HD:Users:Ronnie:Pictures:Test Folder 2:ABC:"
set target_folder to "Macintosh HD:Users:Ronnie:Pictures:Test Folder 3:ABC:"

--above not needed in Finder tell block

tell application "Finder"
    set fileNames to (name of files of alias tf1) --we get the names of the files here; "name" filters, so does "files"
    set matchNames to (name of files of alias tf2) --and the names of the files we want to match in testing
    repeat with thisName in fileNames --repeat loop is necessary for this
        if thisName is in matchNames then
            --notice the concatenating of folder and name to make new alias that gets copied
            duplicate alias (tf1 & thisName) to alias target_folder
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work the way it should! Ever so awesome. I have a lot to learn. I need to take some time and see how exactly it works. But thank you again for your willing and competent work. I tried it with a selection of just 4 files in TF2  and it found 3 out of 4. A search of TF1 indicates that the file is not there so the program seems to be working right. I will feedback about my experience as I go along.